# diferencia de días de dos fechas en angular 8

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de hacer una validación cuando sean x díasy x porcentaje, se asigne un label como un alerta; la validación de porcentaje me funciona perfectamente. [imagen de la vista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoKsE.png)

El código en html es el siguiente:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ordenes">

<span id="days" *ngIf="ordenes.avance > 66">
  <div  class="successful" matTooltip="Va muy bien siga asi">
    <mat-label>Excelente
      <mat-icon >done </mat-icon> 
    </mat-label>
</div>     
</span>
</td>
```

En el ts estoy usando moment:

```
fechadiferencia(){
let requerido = moment(this.fecha.fecha_requerida);
let creacion = moment(this.fecha.fecha_solicitud);
let dias = creacion.diff(requerido,"day");
$("#days").text(dias)}
```

En un tutorial que revise, la variable x la pasa al html y obtiene la diferencia de días, pero tengo que usar la variable en la condición para poder asignar el label a esos dias. Soy novato en angular, alguien me podría ayudar por favor. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo el calculo de la resta del día mas reciente menos el día mas viejo, mira el ejemplo:

```
let days = new Date().getDay() - new Date("2013-02-20T12:01:04.753Z").getDay();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero lo logres solucionar desde la base de datos por medio de una consulta y fue mucho mejor, pero muchísimas gracias